# How to check if twitter username exists in python

Tags: python-3.x, twitter, twitter-oauth

I want to check the twitter username exists or not in python. With API or without API is all acceptable.

```
consumer_key = '...'  
consumer_secret     = '...'  
access_token_key    = '...' 
access_token_secret = '...'  
auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
auth.set_access_token(access_token_key, access_token_secret)

api = tweepy.API(auth, wait_on_rate_limit=True, wait_on_rate_limit_notify=True)

def twitter_is_alive(twitter_name):
    try:
        # I don't know how to check it
        return True
    except:
        return False
  
twitter_is_alive('@valid') return True
twitter_is_alive('@invalid') return False
```

I am really appreciate your help!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [GET users/show endpoint](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/v1/accounts-and-users/follow-search-get-users/api-reference/get-users-show) to check if it returns a user. The endpoint returns a variety of information about the user specified by the required user_id or screen_name parameter.

I see you're using the Python Tweepy library, and I believe it's the [API.get_user method](http://docs.tweepy.org/en/latest/api.html?highlight=users%20show#API.get_user).